# Java Bitwise Or Between Byte and Int

Tags: java, binary, bit-manipulation, twos-complement, sign-extension

I am trying to perform a bitwise or on a `byte` value I have in Java.

For example, I am running:

```
byte b = (byte)0b11111111;
int result = 0 | b;
```

My expected result for this would be `0b00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111`, or `255`. However, I am receiving `-1`, or `0b11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111`.

I'm assuming that Java converts my `byte` into an `int` via sign extension before performing the operation, and I was just curious if there was a way to get my desired result without using a bit mask (`0b11111111`).

Comment: "without using a bit mask" The answer is to use a bitmask. There isn't really a way around that in Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a bit mask is the standard solution to disable sign extension when converting a `byte` to an `int`. You'll just have to accept this slice of Java ugliness.

```
int result = 0 | (b & 0xFF);
```